# after editing a cell in datatableEditor the output text still display the old Value primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am using JSF 2.2 with PrimeFaces 5.0. I have a dataTable with cell-editing.

I am having the dataTable inside dialog when I set editMode="cell", the outputtext after editing it's doesn't appear, but when i put the datatable edit outside dialog, it's work.When I inspect the element of datatable  it's empty but if i put the datatable edtor outside dialog the outPut element isn't empty

===>when i click to edit the cell the input have the new value but the outputext still have the old value

===>so here my page

```
<ui:composition  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
   <f:view>
   <h:form id="lotRecepForm">
        <p:dataTable value="#{lotRecpBean.liste}" 
                     var="lotRecp"                        
                     id="tbl">                                                                 
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <span class="nomColonneTab">Lot Réception</span>                        
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lotRecp.codeLotReception}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <span class="nomColonneTab">Entrant</span>  
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lotRecp.entrant.designation}"/>
            </p:column>               
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <span class="nomColonneTab">Date Réception</span>  
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lotRecp.dateReception}">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <span class="nomColonneTab">Quantite Livrée</span>  
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{lotRecp.quantiteLivree}"/>
            </p:column>               
            <p:column headerText="Action"  exportable="false" styleClass="nomColonneTab">                                          
                    <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-w"
                                     update=":content:modif"
                                     oncomplete="PF('w_edit').show();" styleClass="buttonAction">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{lotRecp}" target="#{lotRecpBean.currentLotReception}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
            </p:column>                 
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
     <p:dialog  id="modif" width="80%" widgetVar="w_edit" modal="true" >                    
    <p:tabView  > 
        <p:tab  title="Controle de Réception ">                  
            <h:form>
               <h:panelGrid>                      
                <p:dataTable id="data1" value="#{normeMicroEBean.listOfNorme(lotRecpBean.currentLotReception.entrant)}" 
                             var="item" editable="true" editMode="cell" >                           
                    <p:column headerText="Valeur Controle" styleClass="ui-editable-column"> 
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText  value="#{item.valeurControle}" /></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{item.valeurControle}" style="width: 50%"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>                               
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column width="15%" headerText="Testeur">
                        <p:cellEditor >
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.testeurCR.nom}" /></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input">
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{item.testeurCR.nom}" style="width:50%">
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{personnelBean.liste}"   var="perso" itemLabel="#{perso.nom}" itemValue="#{perso}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
                            </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>                                                        
                </p:dataTable>
            </h:panelGrid>
         <h:form>
        </p:tab>  
      <p:tab  title="Info lot de Réception">                   
            <h:form>    
                <p:panelGrid id="idPanel">                                                                                                        
                    <p:row>
                        <p:column><p:outputLabel value="QuantiteLivree:"                   for="quantiteLivree" /></p:column>
                        <p:column><p:inputText id="quantiteLivree" value="#{lotRecpBean.currentLotReception.quantiteLivree}" title="QuantiteLivree" /></p:column>
                        <p:column><p:outputLabel  value="QuantiteRecue:" for="quantiteRecue" /></p:column>
                        <p:column><p:inputText id="quantiteRecue" value="#{lotRecpBean.currentLotReception.quantiteRecue}" title="QuantiteRecue" /></p:column>
                        <p:column><p:outputLabel value="NumBonLivraison:" for="numBonLivraison" /></p:column>
                        <p:column><p:inputText id="numBonLivraison" value="#{lotRecpBean.currentLotReception.numBonLivraison}" title="NumBonLivraison" /></p:column>                          
                    </p:row>                                                                                                                                    
                </p:panelGrid>                        
                <div>
                    <p:commandButton action="#{lotRecpBean.update()}" value="Enregistrer" styleClass="button"
                                     style="float: right" oncomplete="PF('lotRecepTable').filter();PF('w_edit').hide();" />               
                </div>  
            </h:form>
        </p:tab>    
    </p:tabView> 
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Do you somehow have nested forms by surrounding the dialog with another form?

Comment: thanks @JaqenH'ghar i edit my page u can see it above,i have one principal form (inside it there's i datatable and button to show my dialog "modif")outside this form i have my dialog, {<f:view><h:form><p:datatable></p:dataTable></h:form><p:dialog><h:form></h:form></p:dialog></f:view>}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I fixed the problem , it's come from the value of datatable ===> the value of datatable editor must be a list and not a method which return a list datatable editor work just with a list 1-

```
 <p:dataTable id="data1" value="#{normeMicroEBean.listOfNorme}" 
                             var="item" editable="true" editMode="cell" >
```

I create a list in the managed bean t and in the button i execute the method to full the list created in the managed bean . thank you for your response